# Trying to code jQuery HTML5 chat box program with mouse click event response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chat, echo

I am having issues coding a chat box program for a school project. I am having 3 problems with the program. First, my chat message does not post properly in my chat box. Secondly, I want to be able to click exit and have it close to window but am not completely sure how to do it. Lastly, I would like the chat to echo the message or to have ahard coded response at the least. I'm researching how to do that I'm not quite sure how to do this. I have a style sheet and html. Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src=http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jQuery.css">



//my issues seem to be in my Javascript between here************************************



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submitmsg').click(function(){
            var message = $('#usermsg').val()
            var old = $('#chatbox').html()

            $('#chatbox').html(old + '<p>' + message + '</p>');
        });
    });
</script>
<script >
    function close_window(url){
        var newWindow = window.open('', '_self', ''); //open the current window
        window.close(url);
    };
</script>


//and here*****************************************************************************
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <p class="welcome">Welcome <b></b></p>

//Possible issue here*******************************************************************
        <p class="logout"><a id="exit" href="#" onclick="window.close();">Exit Chat</a></p>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="chatbox">
        <p>Here's our chat data</p>
    </div>

    <form name="message" action="">
        <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
        <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
    </form>
</div>      
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my css:

```
body {
font:12px arial;
color: #222;
text-align:center;
padding:35px; }

form, p, span {
    margin:0;
    padding:0; }

input { 
    font:12px arial; }

a {
    color:#0000FF;
    text-decoration:none; }

a:hover { 
    text-decoration:underline; }

#wrapper, #loginform {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-bottom:25px;
    background:#EBF4FB;
    width:75%;
    border:1px solid #ACD8F0; }

#loginform { 
    padding-top:18px; }

#loginform p { 
    margin: 5px; }

#chatbox {
    text-align:left;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#fff;
    height:270px;
    width:430px;
    border:1px solid #ACD8F0;
    overflow:auto; }

#chatbox p {
    padding:1em;
    margin:1em;
    background:#E6E6E6;
    border:1px solid #BDBDBD;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
}

#usermsg {
    width:395px;
    border:1px solid #ACD8F0; }

#submit { 
    width: 60px; }


.welcome { 
    float:left; }

.logout { 
    float:right; }

.msgln { 
    margin:0 0 2px 0; }
```

Some of the css is unnecessary I'm pretty sure but when I tried taking some out it caused issues. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post enough code that will focus only on one problem rather than throw some code at others and ask for fixes.

Comment: Not certain what expected result is?

Comment: My expected result is for the input message to post in the 'chatbox' area. Also I'm trying to get the window to close upon clicking Exit chat. Also I am really not sure how to echo the input message back.

Comment: I have gone in and tried to point out where I feel my issues are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try copying the following - i put the styling into the head, moved the javascript to the end, and swapped the input for a button. This is ties to the onclick and appends the new comment into the chat window. It works, but could be done better, also I have not addressed the issue of closing the window, but this does post the new comment into the chat region.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<style>
body {
font:12px arial;
color: #222;
text-align:center;
padding:35px; }

form, p, span {
    margin:0;
    padding:0; }

input { 
    font:12px arial; }

a {
    color:#0000FF;
    text-decoration:none; }

a:hover { 
    text-decoration:underline; }

#wrapper, #loginform {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-bottom:25px;
    background:#EBF4FB;
    width:75%;
    border:1px solid #ACD8F0; }

#loginform { 
    padding-top:18px; }

#loginform p { 
    margin: 5px; }

#chatbox {
    text-align:left;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#fff;
    height:270px;
    width:430px;
    border:1px solid #ACD8F0;
    overflow:auto; }

#chatbox p {
    padding:1em;
    margin:1em;
    background:#E6E6E6;
    border:1px solid #BDBDBD;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
}

#usermsg {
    width:395px;
    border:1px solid #ACD8F0; }

#submit { 
    width: 60px; }


.welcome { 
    float:left; }

.logout { 
    float:right; }

.msgln { 
    margin:0 0 2px 0; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <p class="welcome">Welcome</p>
        <p class="logout"><a id="exit" href="#" onclick="window.close();">Exit Chat</a></p>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="chatbox">
        <p>Here's our chat data</p>
    </div>

    <form name="message">
        <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
        <button type="button" id="submitmsg" value="send">Send</button>    
    </form>
</div> 

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submitmsg').click(function(){
            var message = $('#usermsg').val();
            $('#chatbox').append('<p>' + message + '</p>');
            $('#usermsg').val('');
        });
    });

 function close_window(url){
        var newWindow = window.open('', '_self', ''); //open the current window
        window.close(url);
    };
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is great thanks. How would I add echo to this so it repeats the message entered back to me?

Comment: sorry - i dont understnad - if you type in a message Eg "test" into the input - it will put "test" into the window. Is that not what you want? what do you mean by "echoing back to you?

Comment: I want the program to repeat my message back like it was the server replying

Answer (score 0):

one problem is that you are using a form that then posts to the same page - reloading it.
I copied your code into a testpage (called chatTest.html) and got the following url after hitting the send button:

```
chatTest.html?usermsg=test+message&submitmsg=Send
```

your message does get posted into the chat section but is then removed when the page reloads. and because you are not specifying a method - it is treating it as a get form and posting the message as a querystring appended to the url.

if you are planning on saving the comments to a database, then you should change the action of the form to a different php page, process the results and return the saved content into the chat section- perhaps using Ajax so that you don;t have to reload the page on every chat submission.

Comment: I haven't learned use of php and am just learning about ajax. How would I do what you're describing?

Comment: That is great thanks. How would I add echo to this so it repeats the message entered back to me?

Comment: sorry - i dont understnad - if you type in a message Eg "test" into the input - it will put "test" into the window. Is that not what you want? what do you mean by "echoing back to you?  - what do you expect to see if the message is "Hello"? at the moment - this will return "hello" as a posted message in the chat window.

Comment: I'm wondering how to code a response to what the user types. I do want the user's message to post in the chat box but I'm not sure how to program a response

Comment: so you want it to be a system response? such as if the message was "what year is it?" - you want a response to be "2016"? this would require a database with a series of expected answers and would more more challenging to try to match a question to your stored answers.

Comment: It would work if it was just a general statement such as "servers are busy" or if it could repeat the initial message back, repeating it.

Comment: no idea sorry - this is when you need to decides what you are doing and try to solve it yourself.good luck and happy coding